# String with optional double quotes converted to a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I do have some possible string formats that I am trying to convert to a list but I am having some trouble when there are double quotes in the string , which is supposed to be converted to a list.

 For the simple format of: `'test 3,9,tag1,G,comment 1'` 
 can be easily converted with the command :  `values = line.split(',')`
and get the result of `values = ['test 3','9','tag1','G','comment 1']` .

The problem starts when the format of the string looks like : `'test 4,77,tag2,Y,"comment 2, comment 3"'` which should be converted to a list like : `['test 4','77','tag2','Y','"comment 2, comment 3"']`

Or the format: `'test 6,1,"tag2, tag3, tag4",Y,"comment 2, comment 3"'` which should be converted to `['test 6','1','"tag2, tag3, tag4"','Y','"comment 2, comment 3"']` .

Obviously, if I use the `line.split(',')` command to the above strings I will get the list `['test 6','1','"tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4"','Y','"comment 2', 'comment 3"']` which is not the correct one.

My next step is going to be converting the information inside the double quotes to a list like : `['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']` , but this will be very simple once I manage to convert them to a separate string .

I considered using a regex solution but I don't seem to get it right.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let me guess, these strings are coming from a `.csv` file? Do you really want to keep the double-quotes after parsing? Usually the double-quotes are there to say "ignore the commas inside the quotes", but the logical value does *not* include the quotes, so you'd actually end up with `['test 6','1','tag2, tag3, tag4','Y','comment 2, comment 3']`. Do you really want the double-quotes preserved?

Comment: If you're reading a .csv, starting by using `csv.reader` from the standard Python libraries will save you a lot of work writing something that does exactly the same thing. With the result you get from that, splitting fields that still need splitting would be straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel.  There are lots of edge conditions for parsing CSVs that the existing `csv` module handles well.  Use the `csv.reader()` functionality to read the columns correctly and then you can post-process columns that need it:

input.csv

```
test 3,9,tag1,G,comment 1
test 4,77,tag2,Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
test 6,1,"tag2, tag3, tag4",Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
```

test.py

```py
import csv

with open('input.csv','r',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        line[1] = int(line[1])        # sample post-read processing
        line[2] = line[2].split(', ')
        line[4] = line[4].split(', ')
        print(line)
```

Output:

```py
['test 3', 9, ['tag1'], 'G', ['comment 1']]
['test 4', 77, ['tag2'], 'Y', ['comment 2', 'comment 3']]
['test 6', 1, ['tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4'], 'Y', ['comment 2', 'comment 3']]
```

### Edit per comment

Per [`csv.reader` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader):

> *csvfile* can be any object which supports the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called — [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) and list objects are both suitable.

From the comment it appears you have a byte stream.  Simply wrap it in a `TextIOWrapper` that decodes the stream so it returns strings instead of bytes:

```py
import csv
import io

# This is a file-like object returning a byte stream,
# like OPs comment.
csv_file = open('input.csv','rb')

with io.TextIOWrapper(csv_file,encoding='utf8') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        line[1] = int(line[1])        # sample post-read processing
        line[2] = line[2].split(', ')
        line[4] = line[4].split(', ')
        print(line)
```

And if you already have the data in a string, wrap it in `StringIO`:

```py
import csv
import io

data = '''\
test 3,9,tag1,G,comment 1
test 4,77,tag2,Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
test 6,1,"tag2, tag3, tag4",Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
'''

with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for line in r:
        line[1] = int(line[1])        # sample post-read processing
        line[2] = line[2].split(', ')
        line[4] = line[4].split(', ')
        print(line)
```

`csv.reader` also supports iterating over lists of strings, so this works as well:

```py
import csv

data = '''\
test 3,9,tag1,G,comment 1
test 4,77,tag2,Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
test 6,1,"tag2, tag3, tag4",Y,"comment 2, comment 3"
'''

r = csv.reader(data.splitlines())
for line in r:
    line[1] = int(line[1])        # sample post-read processing
    line[2] = line[2].split(', ')
    line[4] = line[4].split(', ')
    print(line)
```

Comment: That is a good solution but the issue is that I don't have the csv file locally. It is supposed to come from a file upload from my Django app . The type of the object is `django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile` and the only way I managed to read it is with the command     `file_data = csv_file.read().decode("utf-8")` , which returns the content of the file to a string

Comment: @FloraBiletsiou That information should be added to your question.  `csv.reader` is still the right solution.  It accepts a "file-like object".  Basically, anything with a `.read()` method.  It also expects Unicode strings, but you can wrap your `csv_file` byte stream to decode.  I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly. This might not be the best solution but it does the job.

```py
def my_splitter(input_string):
    temp_list = input_string.split('"')
    temp_list = [item.split(',') for item in temp_list]
    output_list = []
    for item in temp_list:
        output_list += [s for s in item if s]
    return output_list

input_string = 'test 6,1,"tag2, tag3, tag4",Y,"comment 2, comment 3"'
output_list =  my_splitter(input_string)
```

```py
>>> output_list
['test 6', '1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'Y', 'comment 2', 'comment 3']
```

In the function, first you split the string by ("). And you get the following list:

```py
['test 6,1,', 'tag2, tag3, tag4', ',Y,', 'comment 2, comment 3', '']
```

Next, you split each element in that list by (,) and you get the following list:

```py
[['test 6', '1', ''], ['tag2', ' tag3', ' tag4'], ['', 'Y', ''], ['comment 2', ' comment 3'], ['']]
```

Finally, you loop through each sub-list and strip the elements of wite space in the start and end, and only append the items if they are not just white space. This is the final output:

```py
['test 6', '1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'Y', 'comment 2', 'comment 3']
```

Comment: This may work for the couple of sample lines but `csv.reader()` handles column values that have commas double quotes and new lines in them as well. It’s the right solution for the job.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you for the information.